# Why must the characteristic polynomial of an $n\times n$ matrix have $n+1$ terms?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix and has a non-zero determinant, why must all the terms in $$\det(\lambda I-A)=c_1\lambda^n+c_2\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots+c_n\lambda+c_{n+1}$$ be non-zero. I have trouble showing this to be valid. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Who said that? It's not true. For example, the charcteristic polynomial associated to $\left(\begin{array}{rr}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$ has characteristic polynomial $\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda & 1\\-1&\lambda\end{array}\right) = \lambda^2+1$, with zero linear term.

Comment: The claim is not true for the diagonal $n\times n$ matrix with entries $e^{2ki\pi/n},$ $k=0,1,\ldots, n-1,$ on the main diagonal. The characteristic polynomial is equal $\lambda^n-1.$

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well, if you drop the requirement of nonzero determinant then it is definitely false, since the constant term of the characteristic polynomial is the determinant, so any non-invertible matrix definitely fails to satisfy the condition.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This is what I am trying to say. It can only be false, and it has "nothing" to do with the determinant (in this sense). The two first sentences of your answer make this clear.

Comment: @DietrichBurde the way you framed your comment is perhaps a bit strange since you included the word "even" and non-zero determinant is a necessary condition for characteristic polynomial to have all of its terms non-zero. But of course, we all agree that it's far from sufficient, unless $n=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is false. Given any monic polynomial $p(\lambda)$ of degree $n$, you can find an $n\times n$ matrix whose characteristic polynomial is precisely $p(\lambda)$. If $p(0)\neq 0$, then $A$ will have nonzero determinant (and conversely).

Explicitly, if you take the matrix
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccccr}
0 & 0 &  \cdots & 0 & -a_0\\
1 & 0 &  \cdots & 0 & -a_1\\
0 & 1 &  \cdots & 0 & -a_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0  & \cdots & 1 & -a_{n-1}
\end{array}\right)$$
then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$p(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A) = \lambda^n + a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots + a_2\lambda^2 + a_1\lambda + a_0.$$
This matrix is called the *companion matrix of $p(\lambda)$*. In addition, the matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if $a_0\neq 0$, and $\det(A) = (-1)^na_0$.

Comment: Is there a reason why that last term has to be non zero for the matrix to be invertible?

Comment: @mostvenerablesir Because the constant term is equal to $(-1)^n$ times the determinant, **as it says in the post**.